# Giving firstResponder to UISegmentControl while UIPopOver is active?

Tags: objective-c, uipopovercontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

Running into an issue and my searches have turned up nothing. I have an app where I need a segment control object(on the VC that launches the popover) to stay active and touchable when i have a popover active. Is this even possible?

EDIT:
Solution below:

```
self.myPopOver.passthroughViews = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:_segPopOverControl, nil];
```

Had to init the passthroughViews for the popover because there were none in use already. Added the UISegmentedController to the list and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it to the popover controller's `passthroughViews` property.

```
NSArray *oldPassthroughViews = myPopoverController.passthroughViews;
myPopoverController.passthroughViews = [[NSArray
    arrayWithArray:myPopoverController.passthroughViews]
    arrayByAddingObject:mySegmentedControl];
```

Comment: This got it. Thank you sir. Needed a slight variation but you led me down the right path. Cheers.'self.myPopOver.passthroughViews = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:_segPopOverControl, nil];'

Comment: Basically there were not any objects in the passthroughviews, so just had to take out the oldPassthrough part and init the views array with my segmentedController